# Accessing an instance throws exception - NSDictionary NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am a beginner in Objective-C and do struggle a bit with dictionaries and arrays.

My goal is to create a table view where every cell contains a picture from a server. The url for the pic comes from a JSON call. I downloaded the example from Apple called "lazy table view" and tried to merge it with the one I found inside a Standford iOS Class. So far everything works, besides the picture. Xcode throws the following exception, once I try to access the icon:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary Icon]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b845ff0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary Icon]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b845ff0'
```

The code in question looks like this:

```
@interface FlickrPhotosTVC : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *photos; 
@end

@interface ClRecord : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *Icon;
#define FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE @"title"

ClRecord *clRecord = self.photos[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [clRecord valueForKeyPath:FLICKR_PHOTO_TITLE]; // works
if (clRecord.Icon) NSLog(@"test"); // throws exeption
```

Somehow this seems to be releated with the types. Trying to access an array, while accesing a dictionory or similar. I found some releated posts on stack, but could not solve it so far.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Found this article recently which you may find useful... http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/nsdictionary.html

Answer (score 0):

The objects stored in self.photos seems to be dictionaries objects and not ClRecord objects. The error you get say that you are calling Icon method on a dictionary object.

Check where you fill your photos array to make sure you put ClRecord objects in it and not dictionaries objects.

Comment: this might be the right track, I changed the following line:
NSDictionary *photos = self.photos[indexPath.row];
to: 
ClRecord *clRecord = self.photos[indexPath.row];

and declared CLRecord to be of NSObject.

I was also wondering, why the title text for exaelmp still works. The thing is, that the example from stanford is using NSDictionaries while the one from Apple is using an array and I can not figure out how to merge the examples in this particular case. Can you hint me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do `NSLog(@"My photos array is ---%@",self.photos);` 
This will give you what exactly you have in your array. 
 
 Case 1: If you have a dictionary objects then :-  
             You should do `NSDictionary *dict = self.photos[indexPath.row];` `ClRecord *clRecord = [dict objectForKey:@"YourKeyForImage"];`

Case2: If you have images as you expect, then make sure you import ClRecord header file, you have non nil object at your specified [indexPath.row] index and other necessary initializations. 

  Hope this helps. [Link1](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/08/iphone-programming-tutorial-populating-uitableview-with-an-nsarray/)